# Highchart doesn't connect lines

Tags: highcharts

I send following data to highstock line chart.

```
 [
   {
      "name":"200",
      "data":[
         [
            1529308800000,
            100
         ]
      ]
   },
   {
      "name":"200",
      "data":[
         [
            1530234000000,
            100
         ]
      ]
   }
]
```

I want to connect points in my chart.but it doesn't connect points. In here x axis is date time and y axis is  percentage. In here some points are drown in same coordinate. can someone help me to do this?

Comment: Your format is wrong, see: https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/series.line.data -> this should be: `[ [x, y], [x, y], [x, y], ... , [x, y] ]`, not `[ [x, y, x, y], [x, y, x, y], ... ]]`

Comment: Im sorry .Its a mistake. I edited my question

Comment: this is my chart https://jsfiddle.net/wc48bzo6/6/

Comment: Still, my comment is correct: your format is wrong: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/wc48bzo6/7/ (use just one series).

Comment: can I use different "name" and "data" in same chart and draw line between them? as in my question?   @PawełFus

Comment: No, because that's different series.